# Another :Unable to create a constant value of type

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Eveytime I think I am getting a handle on this stuff.

Full Error:

Unable to create a constant value of type 'Models.staffnames'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.

Versions: .Net 4 EF 4

I think it has something to do with DU and db.UserProfiles being Enumerable but when I try to push it back to make everything IQueryable the whole thing blows up. As it stands right now the error occurs when building the supportlist.

It is interesting to note that the only time this problem seems to crop up is when I am working with the Roles provider.  Which in the past I just dumped it out into a for loop.

Any help would be appreciated.

Code:

```
IEnumerable<MembershipUser> du = Roles.GetUsersInRole("Dealer").Select(u => Membership.GetUser(u)).AsEnumerable();
        IQueryable<staffnames> du_up = du.Join(db.UserProfiles.AsEnumerable(), mu => (Guid)mu.ProviderUserKey, up => up.UserID, (mu, up) => new staffnames
        {
            UserId = (Guid)mu.ProviderUserKey,
            FirstName = up.FirstName,
            LastName = up.LastName
        }).AsQueryable();
        List<MemberSupportModel> support = db.Wins_support.Where(s=>s.dealerid == uid && !s.closed).Select(s=> new MemberSupportModel{
             aeramanagerack = s.aeramanagerack,
             amgrname = du_up.Where(a => a.UserId == s.aeramanger).Select(a=>a.FirstName+" "+a.LastName).FirstOrDefault(),
             aeramangerackdate = s.aeramangerackdate,
             atypedesc = _atype.Where(wt => wt.Value == s.atypeid).Select(wt => wt.Description).FirstOrDefault(),
             wtypedesc = _wtype.Where(wt => wt.Value == s.typeid).Select(wt => wt.Description).FirstOrDefault(),
             comment =s.comment,
             dateSubmitted = s.dateSubmitted,
             vdate =s.vdate,
             venuename = s.Venues_Logs.Venue.venueName           
        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the line `amgrname = du_up.Where(...` because `du_up` is a collection of a non-primitive type *in memory*, hence the exception. `AsQueryable` doesn't help here, in-memory is in-memory, you can't change that.

I would try to load the data you need from the DB separately and then merge your `du_up` collection with the collection of data loaded from the DB:

```
// LINQ to Objects in memory
IEnumerable<MembershipUser> du = Roles.GetUsersInRole("Dealer")
    .Select(u => Membership.GetUser(u));

// LINQ to Objects in memory
// db.UserProfiles.AsEnumerable() loads whole UserProfiles table from DB
IEnumerable<staffnames> du_up = du.Join(db.UserProfiles.AsEnumerable(),
    mu => (Guid)mu.ProviderUserKey, up => up.UserID, (mu, up) => new staffnames
    {
        UserId = (Guid)mu.ProviderUserKey,
        FirstName = up.FirstName,
        LastName = up.LastName
    });

// LINQ to Entites = database query
List<MemberSupportModel> support = db.Wins_support
    .Where(s=>s.dealerid == uid && !s.closed)
    .Select(s=> new // anonymous result object
    {
        aeramanagerack = s.aeramanagerack,
        aeramanger = s.aeramanger, // needed later for the du_up Where clause
        aeramangerackdate = s.aeramangerackdate,
        atypedesc = _atype.Where(wt => wt.Value == s.atypeid)
                          .Select(wt => wt.Description)
                          .FirstOrDefault(),
        wtypedesc = _wtype.Where(wt => wt.Value == s.typeid)
                          .Select(wt => wt.Description)
                          .FirstOrDefault(),
        comment = s.comment,
        dateSubmitted = s.dateSubmitted,
        vdate = s.vdate,
        venuename = s.Venues_Logs.Venue.venueName
    })
    .AsEnumerable() // execute database query
    // now LINQ to Objects in memory again
    // Copy values from anonymous result object and select data from du_up
    .Select(s => new MemberSupportModel
    {
        aeramanagerack = s.aeramanagerack,
        amgrname = du_up.Where(a => a.UserId == s.aeramanger)
                        .Select(a => a.FirstName + " " + a.LastName)
                        .FirstOrDefault(),
        aeramangerackdate = s.aeramangerackdate,
        atypedesc = s.atypedesc,
        wtypedesc = s.wtypedesc,
        comment = s.comment,
        dateSubmitted = s.dateSubmitted,
        vdate = s.vdate,
        venuename = s.venuename
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you yet again Slauma. That seems like an awful lot of work to get a name from the user profile, maybe this might be a case where a stored proc would be a better call?

Comment: also wouldnt it be bad practice to load the whole user profile table from the db? Or is it a matter of preference?

Comment: @Chris: Unless you write a Stored Proc you don't really have an alternative to loading the profile table from the DB because the ASP.NET membership tables are not part of your EF model, so you can't write any LINQ to Entities queries that join your EF model with the membership tables. I would say: If you don't have performance problems and the UserProfiles table isn't huge and isn't expected to become huge over time stick with the approach above, otherwise: Stored Proc.

Comment: @Saluma upon reviewing the design, I over thought the objective and actually had no need to reference the membership model. But the additional learning was a bonus so it all worked out. Also I added a bool IsStaff field to the userprofile table that will limit the pull. Thanks again for your help.